# ID in small mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a couple of small table with few entries and **I'm wondering if I should add an ID to these tables**. I've read on other posts that a primarily key is preferred for optimal performance. I'm using InnoDB tables.

**If the answer is yes, what is the best way to structure the small tables (status and level)? Is it better to call the ID or the name directly?**

By "small" tables I mean 3 to 10 rows.

Table Status:

```
column ID, name
1, Open
2, Closed
3, Maintenance
```

Table Level:

```
Column ID, name
1, easy
2, medium
3, hard
```

Main table
Should it be:

```
Columns ID, name_item, status_item, level_item
1, name1, 1, 3
2, name2, 1, 1
3, name3, 2, 2
```

Or:

```
1, name1, Open, hard
2, name2, Open, easy
3, name3, Closed, medium
```

If I put the ID in the main table, I need to run a second query to display the name of the status/level in the interface.

**UPDATE:**
A better approach is maybe to store only IDs in the small tables and in my php page write:
`$level = 'translated_level'.$info_level->ID;
echo $this->lang->line('level');`

That could also simplify multilinguage handling

Comment: How small is _small_? 5 rows, 500? 5000? It is also unclear exactly what you're asking, could you please **explicitly** state your question

Comment: below 10 rows. I clarified the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Status and Level values won't change I would use an ENUM type for those columns and set the possible values, that way you avoid having to join two other tables.

status_item would be `ENUM('Open', 'Closed', 'Maintenance')`

level_item would be `ENUM('Easy', 'Medium', 'Hard')`

Comment: ENUMs have two huge disadvantages: 1. they are a proprietary, non standard extension, so data and code are not portable any more to other database engines. Basically you violate the sql standard by using them. 2. they can cause _huge_ issues even if you stay inside the MySQL eco system if you try to exchange data with other systems. So in general I personally would advise against them.

Comment: I didn't realize that mysql supported enum ?  Thought that was only commercial database servers like SQL or Access, or Oracle (not the MySQL product they acquired)

Comment: Also sorting by an ENUM column can lead to surprising results :-)

Comment: As far as I know it does not require a commercial MySQL server, I use them for one particular thing on my personal site and I don't have a commercial server. Also considering the values he would be using for the enums I can't think of a situation where you would want to sort the data by those columns. However if he doesn't want to use an enum I still don't think having 3 tables is the best solution. Maybe using a varchar for the 3 states?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should have an id for each rows of your table. Most tables should have a primary key, and each table can have only ONE primary key.

You can save the id in your main table and still get the data you need in one query.

```
SELECT main.id, main.name_item, status.name, level.name
FROM main
JOIN status ON status.id = main.id
JOIN levels ON level.id = main.id
```

Which will return the result you want to achieve

```
Row ID, name_item, status_item, level_item  
1, name1, Open, hard
2, name2, Open, easy
3, name3, Closed, medium
```

Comment: But this a horrible performance, since you require two joins. Joins are the part in the relational data model that are the biggest issue if it comes to performance.